# Numeric alias in Doctrine 2 DQL

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

I need a numeric alias in Select in DQL:
  `SELECT c.id, dsv63.name AS 102`
But after that I get an error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 423: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '102'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a Doctrine2 problem, you can't use integers as names in MySQL.

There are reserved names for tables too, for example, you can't name your table `where` like `SELECT * FROM foo AS where` will throw you an exception.

What you can do, is prepend a character, for example

`SELECT c.id, dsv63.name AS _102`

Or quote it

`SELECT c.id, dsv64.name AS '102'`